# How to php inside <<<DELIMETER

Tags: php, wordpress, html

This is my code:

```
$footer_rotem =
<<<DELIMETER

      <div class="tile red"><img src="http://localhost/be/wp-content/plugins/Rotem%20Gallery/img/4.png"></div>
      <div class="tile red"><img src="http://localhost/be/wp- content/plugins/Rotem%20Gallery/img/5.jpg"></div>

DELIMETER;

return $footer_rotem;
```

I want to add some PHP in the img src like:

```
<img src="<?php echo 'url' ?>"/>
```

But how can I do that inside this-

```
 <<<DELIMETER
```

Comment: [heredoc syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).... the PHP Documentation is really easy too use for finding this kind of information

Comment: As Mark said, see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). Also, your example is pointless (you don't need PHP to echo a literal string) and contains a syntax error (no `;`). Please read about how to create a  [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it like this  heredoc is also like double quoted string so you can use variables directly.

```
<<<DELIMETER

  <div class="tile red"><img src="$url"></div> 
  <div class="tile red"><img src="$url"></div>

DELIMETER;
```